# Documents.Open method throws error: "This command is not available because no document is open"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA macro that fails on the line:

```
Set doc = Documents.Open(path, ConfirmConversions:=False, Visible:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
```

with Run-time error 4248: "This command is not available because no document is open"

The problem doesn't occur if I call Documents.Add first... But it's not a perfect solution for me, as I don't want to create empty documents. I'd rather know what's going on, why can't I open any document, unless there is something opened? o.O

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is... 
It works, if I change Visible to True.